# Quadratic Optimization problem with sqrt term

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve a mean-variance (quadratic optimization) problem with a non-linear market impact cost term in there. This is the problem I am trying to solve

$$\max  \alpha a - \gamma x^T \Sigma x - a\sqrt{|x-x_0|} $$

where, $x_0$ is the current portfolio holding.

I am using MATLAB's quadprog program to solve this problem. How can I setup my optimization problem correctly to incorporate the sqrt term in the objective ? I am sure there is a way to do this, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Your problem is not convex due to the square root, therefore quadprog cannot optimize it. Why not use a norm?

Comment: I thought market impacts were more commonly 3/2 power terms?

Comment: Regardless—quadprog will not be able to handle this. As its name implies, it supports only quadratic objectives; and if memory serves, only linear constraints. There is no way to render this objective, or even the $3/2$ version, under those limitations.

Comment: What are the decision variables? Is $a$ a decision variable? Is it only $x$?